# Custom handling WinKey+ArrowKey combination

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is there a possibility to handle `WinKey+ArrowKey` key combination before Windows handle it for `WPFWindow`? With `OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)` I can catch when WinKey and ArrowKey are pressed separately, but not WinKey+ArrowKey combination. Seems that it is handled by system and window only get resizing command. Is there any way to handle this combination before system?

Comment: You can probably steal them with RegisterHotKey() but that makes them active even if your app is not in the foreground.  "Don't do it" is the only good advice.

Comment: @HansPassant How can I then handle WM_HOTKEY for WPF window?

Comment: Type "[wpf] registerhotkey" in the Search box.  58 hits, pretty doubtful you need one more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you will need to use a Global Keyboard Hook.  There is a good project that would get you started in the right direction here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook

To reiterate Hans Passant's warning, this will catch the key combination even if your program is running in the background.  If this is not what you want, then you will need to subscribe and unsubscribe to the events when your program is focused/unfocused or put additional logic in there to detect whether your program is the focused program before taking any action.

If you import the classes from the link, then you can implement them in your code like this (EDIT: this seems to work with KeyValue, but not with KeyCode):

```
GlobalKeyboardHook gkh = new GlobalKeyboardHook();
private bool _winKeyPressed;

public MyConstructor()
{
    gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Left); //37
    gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Up); //38
    gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Right); //39
    gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.Down); //40

    gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.LWin); //91
    gkh.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.RWin); //92

    gkh.KeyDown += gkh_KeyDown;
    gkh.KeyUp += gkh_KeyUp;
}

private void gkh_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{ 
    if (e.KeyValue == 91 || e.KeyValue == 92)
    {
        // left or right windows key was released
        _winKeyPressed = false;
    }
}

void gkh_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyValue == 91 || e.KeyValue == 92)
    {
        // left or right windows key was pressed
        _winKeyPressed = true;
    }

    if (e.KeyValue == 39 && _winKeyPressed == true)
    {
        // right key
        MessageBox.Show("This works.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have found this GlabalKeyboardHook before and tried it, but doesn't help for this key combination. Does it work for you?

Comment: I found the way how make this code work correctly. with some modifications it works stable for WinForm and not so stable for WPFWindow

Comment: @melya - Try it with the e.KeyValue instead of e.KeyCode as I initially recommended.  This implementation works for me.  In the edited answer, I check for the windows key on keydown and keyup and set a boolean accordingly to say whether they are currently holding the windows key.  You can handle the arrow keys with their KeyValue integer constant.

Comment: @melya - Also, setting e.Handled to true will prevent Windows from seeing the keypress once you have handled it.  Remember though that the user may just want to hit the windows key or the right arrow - be careful not to "break" other Windows features.